# Kafka Topic with Compact,Delete does not delete key

Tags: apache-kafka

I have setup a test topic like this one:

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --create --topic testing  --replication-factor 1   --partitions 1 --config "cleanup.policy=compact,delete" --config "retention.ms=900000"  --config "segment.ms=600000" --config "min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01"
```

After this I published some key/values using a script in a continuous fashion.

My expectation is that old keys would start to be deleted after the given `retention.ms`, however the topic keeps growing without any deletions.

Is there something that I am missing regarding the compact,delete cleanup policy?

Comment: Unclear how much data is in your topic, but segment size is default to 1G and only closed segments are deleted or compacted

Comment: I think you nailed it, I totally forgot to check this. I'll test with more data or smaller segment size. Thanks for the idea!